# need help on join query condtion

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, join

I am not much in db queries and I require some help on following .

I have two table structures as follow as 
table1 :

```
Name    Id1 Id2
Jack    1   1
Jack    1   1
Jack    1   1
```

table2 :

```
Name    Id1 Id2
Jack     1   1
```

I used basic join query :

```
select *
from table1 tb1
join table2 tb2 on tb1.id1 = tb2.id1
    and tb2.id2 = tb2.id2
```

output I get :

```
Jack    1   1
Jack    1   1
Jack    1   1
```

But I required following output:

Jack    1   1

Note: I like to show what records is available in table 2 when it combined together!!.. I would like to fetch data with respect table2 only

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this case, you could use "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ..."

Comment: You are joining on `id` column, but your sample data has id1 and id2...

Comment: distinct not provided output.. regarding id, its corrected now

Comment: Your join should also be "join table2 tb2", not "tb1".

Comment: Now you should get only two rows - on which you can use distinct

Comment: _and tb2.id2 = tb2.id2_ will always be true....

Comment: The output you show would not come from the query you show. You SELECT *, so the results would have all of the columns in both tables. Also, the data in all rows is identical, not realistic, but if it is, you have serious problem in your data design/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following (does not uses aliases) ...

```
SELECT table2.Name,
       table2.Id1,
       table2.Id2
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.id1 = table2.id1 AND
               table1.id2 = table2.id2
GROUP BY table2.id1,
         table2.id2;
```

Or try the following (does use aliases)...

```
SELECT tb2.Name,
       tb2.Id1,
       tb2.Id2
FROM table1 tb1
JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb1.id1 = tb2.id1 AND
                   tb1.id2 = tb2.id2
GROUP BY tb2.id1,
         tb2.id2;
```

By performing an `INNER JOIN` on `table2` with `table1` on those key fields you are limiting the output to only those rows from `table1` that match `Id1` and `Id2` in `table2` (Note : Where `JOIN` is not preceded by a `JOIN` type an `INNER JOIN` is performed).  Since multiple rows in `table1` meet this criteria you can limit your results to just one row for each matching set of criteria using `GROUP BY`

This should change the supplied actual query to...

```
SELECT delta.input_name,
       delta.mtcn,
       delta.at‌​tempt_id 
FROM compliance.rtra_transactions rtra_txn
JOIN compliance.GNR_TEST_RUNS delta ON rtra_txn.mtcn_nr = delta.mtcn
                                   AND rtra_txn.attemptid = delta.attempt_id
WHERE rtra_txn.year = 2017
  AND rtra_txn.month = 2
  AND rtra_txn.day = 17
  AND rtra_txn.trns_ts BETWEEN '2017-02-17 00:00:00' AND '2017-02-17 23:59:00'
  AND delta.MATCH_OUTCOME = 'MATCH'
  AND delta.job_name = 'Feb17_Run_1'
  AND rtra_txn.txn_map[ 'TRANSACTIONTYPE' ] IN ( '10', '7' )
GROUP BY delta.mtcn,
         delta.attempt_id;
```

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: its not working. fyi the real query: GNR_TEST_RUNS.input_name,GNR_TEST_RUNS.mtcn,GNR_TEST_RUNS.attempt_id from compliance.rtra_transactions rtra_txn join compliance.GNR_TEST_RUNS delta on rtra_txn.mtcn_nr=delta.mtcn and rtra_txn.attemptid = delta.attempt_id where rtra_txn.year = 2017 and rtra_txn.month = 2 and rtra_txn.day = 17 and rtra_txn.trns_ts between '2017-02-17 00:00:00' and '2017-02-17 23:59:00' and delta.MATCH_OUTCOME ='MATCH' and delta.job_name = 'Feb17_Run_1' and rtra_txn.txn_map['TRANSACTIONTYPE'] in ('10','7') GROUP BY NR_TEST_RUNS.mtcn,GNR_TEST_RUNS.attempt_id

Comment: I have corrected my answer after creating a test database with populated test tables and testing the corrected code against it.  My previous error was caused by the fact that the tables were given aliases, which I rarely use and did not use in my former Answer.  My new answer features versions with and without aliases.  I shall suggest an edit to your question to place the script to create the sample database as an appendix to the question as soon as the Edit Queue becomes available.

Comment: yes. thats how I modified but still drive duplicates. I am getting 113 records. 
See, the second table count is just 91. So the whole query should provide the outcome of 91 only
Fyr,  
select count(*) from compliance.GNR_TEST_RUNS where MATCH_OUTCOME ='MATCH' and job_name = 'Feb17_Run_1' 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: How many records are in `rtra_transactions` after its criteria are applied?  And how many are in `GNR_TEST_RUNS` if you remove just `MATCH_OUTCOME ='MATCH'`?  How many if you remove just `job_name = 'Feb17_Run_1'`?  How many if you remove both?

Comment: more than 10k records..I use hive

Comment: You may have missed my Comment's edit, so I will ask again - How many are in GNR_TEST_RUNS if you remove just MATCH_OUTCOME ='MATCH'? How many if you remove just job_name = 'Feb17_Run_1'? How many if you remove both?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140032/discussion-between-will-mcavoy-and-toonice).

Comment: Sorry, but recent family medical matters in addition to my normal workload have caused me to lose track a little of where we are at.  Are you still pursuing this problem, and if so, then how do things currently stand?

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful... :)

Answer (score 1):

Following query should work :

```
SELECT * FROM TBL2 T2
UNION
SELECT * FROM TBL1 T1;
```

Comment: I think he's looking for "UNION" rather than "UNION ALL" as he wishes to remove duplicate rows.

Comment: Yes. I like to show what records is available in table 2 alone..and I would like to fetch data with respect table2 only

Comment: This will return all rows from `table1` and all rows from `table2`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` as you mentioned in **Biswabid** answer comment  ***I like to show what records is available in table 2 alone***

```
select DISTINCT tb2.*
from table2 tb2
left join table1 tb1 on tb1.id1 = tb2.id1
    and tb1.id2 = tb2.id2
WHERE tb1.id1 IS NULL
```